# Angular 5 maxlength and alphanumeric validation

Tags: angular5

I am trying to display error if user input is not alphanumeric following [this](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-minlength-and-maxlength-validation-example) example, but without success. Error message is always displayed.

This is code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="this.context.risk.contractOrigin === 'Appel_d_offre'">
    <label class="control-label" for="numberTenderInvitation">Numéro d'appel d'offre</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="numberTenderInvitation" name="numberTenderInvitation"
           [(ngModel)]="context.risk.policyId"
           #numberTender="ngModel"
           maxlength="10"
           [pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z \-\']$'"
           required/>
</div>
<small class="errorLabel" [hidden]="!numberTender.errors">
    Le champ comporte une erreur.
</small>
```

Error that I got is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Your pattern has a few problems

1. It is checking for a single character only
   ^ start of string
   [ ... ] match 1
   $ end of string
If you require at least one character you need to add a '+' if 0 or more a '*'

2. You say non-alphanumeric but you are not checking specifically for digits, you should add 0-9 to your pattern

3. Try moving your [\-] after the [\'] so your final pattern is as follows (assuming you want at least one char as input)

```
[pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z0-9 \'\-]+$'"
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of reference I am posting final solution:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="this.context.risk.contractOrigin === 'Appel_d_offre'">
    <label class="control-label" for="numberTenderInvitation">Numéro d'appel d'offre</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="numberTenderInvitation" name="numberTenderInvitation"
           #numberTender="ngModel"
           [(ngModel)]="context.risk.policyId"
           maxlength="10"
           [pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z0-9 \'\-]+$'"
    required/>
    <small class="errorLabel" [hidden]="numberTender.pristine || numberTender.valid">
        Le champ comporte une erreur.
    </small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator). This is required because your `<small` element is likely trying to access numberTender because it's been fully initialized. Try this:

```
<small class="errorLabel" [hidden]="numberTender?.errors">
    Le champ comporte une erreur.
</small>
```

I also removed the `!` so this logic reads: *If number Tender exists **and** it has an errors property*

Comment: Actually it has to have ! as error message has to be hidden if there are no errors, but despite that, neither yours or this solution works. Any idea why? <small class="errorLabel" [hidden]="!(numberTender?.errors.pattern && !focused)

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
      <small  [hidden]="numberTender.valid" class="errorLabel" >
         Le champ comporte une erreur.
      </small>
```